# Excel worksheet_change event

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am wondering if you could help me with the worksheet_Change for two different targets.

MY code is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A50")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub        
             Range("A1:A50").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B1")

 End Sub
```

And it is working, whenever anytjing is updated in column A it is updated and copied in column B(worksheet 2). Now the problem I have is that i want to add another target, B1:B50, and only If that target has the word SUM in it, it should copy and update. The problem is that it is copying but NOT updating anything. My code for that is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A50, B1:B50")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    
    If Target.Address = "TOTAL" Then
             Range("A1:A50").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B1")
       end if
 End Sub
```

What shoudl i do?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused on what `Target` represents. `Target`, in the scope of a `Worksheet_Change` event is the cell(s) being *changed*.

Also, the `Target.Address` will **never** be "TOTAL", so this logic will not work:

```
If Target.Address = "TOTAL"
```

With that in mind, I would do something like this. Create a separate procedure for each range (column A or B). Then use the `Worksheet_Change` event to determine which procedure to call on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A50, B1:B50")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    
 If Target.Column = 1 Then Call RangeA(Target)
 If Target.Column = 2 Then Call RangeB(Target)
End Sub

Sub RangeA(Target as Range)
    Range("A1:A50").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B1")
End Sub

Sub RangeB(Target As Range)

    'Here, you put the code that you want to run when Target is in column B

End Sub
```

Since I'm not exactly sure what you intend to do with Column B, I left the `RangeB` procedure empty for now. You can modify that procedure to do whatever you want, based on the target change in range B1:B50.

Comment: thank you for your help. But my problem is, that i want it to find the name "total" in column A, and if it does then it should copy the same row in column b to a new sheet.

Comment: It seems like you could just use formula to do that.  Why are you relying on the Change event?

Answer (score 0):

How does column B get populated?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A50")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1:A50").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B1")
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B50")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "Total" Then
            MsgBox Target.Address    'do something here
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```