# VBa Code not coming out of loop

Tags: vba, excel

Question looks big but answer for you guys will be simple
I have code that works for first time and not working for second attempt.
I have 2 sheets "Menu" and "Subsheet"
Basically, i have data validation drop-down set on Menu Sheet yes/no values.
**First scenario**
Selecting "Yes" will enable the cells on second sheet (Subsheet)
Selecting "No" will disable cells on second sheet(Subsheet).

**Second scenario,**
User selecting "no" and selecting second sheet will throw a prompt for him to enable cells "ok" and cancel.
Select "ok" will enable cells and value in dropdown will be changed to "yes"
selecting "cancel" in msgprompt  will disable cells and value in dropdown will remain "no"
Msg prompt should not be displayed, if user has selected "yes" in dropdown..

Question:Code works fine, until it comes to second scenario.
User selects "No" and selects second sheet in the message prompt, he selects "no". Now cells are disabled. 
If user comes back to Menu Sheet and selects "***Yes", will not enable cells.***
Not sure what is it not enabling cells now. Please help

Code on Menu Sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Range("A11")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case (Target.Value)
      Case "YES"
        Call uEnable
      Case "NO"
         Call uDisable
         Exit Sub
    End Select
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Code on SubSheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  UDisable
End Sub
```

Code on Module

```
Option Explicit
Private mMessageDisplayed As Boolean
Public Sub uDisable()
  If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents And Not mMessageDisplayed Then
    mMessageDisplayed = True
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Menu").Range("A11") = "NO" Then
      If MsgBox("Cells are locked on current sheet, press ok to Unlock", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("A11") = "YES"
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Subsheet")
          ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
          .Range("E13:E14").Locked = False
          ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
        End With
      Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("A11") = "NO"
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Subsheet")
          ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
          .Range("E13:E14").Locked = True
          ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
        End With
      End If
    Else
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Second module

```
Public Sub uEnable()
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Subsheet")
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
    .Range("E13:E14").Locked = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
  End With
End Sub
```

I tried to use debug method, couldn't identify the root cause.

Two intersect codes

```
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("E42")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim inputCell As Range
        Set inputCell = Range("E43")
            Select Case (Target.Value)
                Case "Specific Days"
                    inputCell.Locked = False
                    inputCell.Activate
                Case Else
                'This handles **ANY** other value in the dropdown
                    inputCell.Locked = True
    '                inputCell.Clear
            End Select
       Application.EnableEvents = True

If Intersect(Target, Range("E29")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case (Target.Value)
            Case "YES"
                Call Notify
            Case "NO"
                 Call NotifyUserGeneral
        End Select
       Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`
```

Comment: I think `uDisable` is locking and protecting the sheet.  While `uEnable` is only unlocking.  Will probably need to unprotect, with the relevant password, too.

Comment: Also seems to be redundant to have a yes/no check in more than one spot. You should just let the one section handle that

Comment: @destination-data I tried to use unprotect/protect in uEnable (modified the code above). But that dint help too!!

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @destination-data Issue still persist. Cells are not getting enabled when the drop is set "yes". I have to select "no" and click "ok" on message prompt to click "ok", so that cells are enabled.

Comment: @DougCoats Sure, do you suggestions on which section to modify? I am out of ideas on it

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `Exit Sub` from underneath `Call uDisable`.  Otherwise `Application.EnableEvents = True` never gets called...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case (Target.Value)
        Case "YES"
            Call uEnable
        Case "NO"
            Call uDisable
            'Exit Sub     <---Can't do this.
    End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

...and there isn't any other code that will turn them back on.  You can't rely on an event handler to set `Application.EnableEvents = True` after you've turned off event handling.

Comment: @Comintem, sure, let me quickly try that!!

Comment: @Comintem, Unfortunately, It dint help. Any idea, why uEnable function module is not getting called when i select "Yes" value in dropdown

Comment: I guess thats the problem. Call uEnable is not calling the module. But not sure what could be the reason. Please suggest if you have any

Comment: @sady - `Public uEnable()` should be `Public Sub uEnable()`. Also, you have `Range("A11")` in `uDisable`, but `Range("A1")` in `Worksheet_Change`.  Are those supposed to be different cells?

Comment: @Comintem - I did a blunder while copying. It was a typo. On the workbook i see it is public Sub uEnable(). Range ("A1") is actually (A11), ?It was a typo again

Comment: @sady - Are you trying to protect and unprotect the worksheets, or the workbooks?

Comment: @Comintem Its actually worksheets. ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xyz"...will this help?

Comment: @sady - Remove the `ActiveWorkbook` inside of all of the `With` blocks, i.e. `.Unprotect Password:="xyz"`.

Comment: @Comintem one more question, In the first line of the worksheet_change event I have used 
  `If Intersect(Target, Range("A11")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`. Instead of exit sub, how to use goto here. Because, I do have other `intersect' code below. I guess its exiting at the first line when it finds no change.

Comment: @sady - Reverse the condition and build an `If ... Else` or `Select Case` structure: `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A11")) Is Nothing Then...` whatever for `A11` changing.

Comment: @Cominten  I gues that did the trick. I used if not and looks like things started to work. However, I would have to fully test it. Thanks a ton bro!!

Comment: @Cominten, I would like to use select case structure instead of if not. Can you please help on how to build it. Here is the two intersect code I was talking about. I have pasted it above

Comment: @sady - That sounds like a different question.  Luckily [it's already been answered here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29461638/4088852)